# Sampling distribution of the length of insects

Tags: probability, statistics

The sampling distribution of length of insect is distributed with a **mean of 12 cm**, and a **standard deviation of 3 cm**.

**A.** What is the probability of an insect being **less than 11 cm** long?

**B.** What is the probability of an insect being **between 10 cm and 12 cm** long?

**C.** What is the probability of an insect that is **between  10 cm and 12 cm** long being ***less*** **than 11 cm** long?

I'm not sure if I am doing it the right way, but that's how I solved it:

**A.** Pr(Y<11)

Z= Y-mean / STD

Z= 11-12 / 3

Z= -0.333...

Area= 0.3707 (from the Z table)

**B.** Pr(10>Y<12)

Z= 100-100 / 15

Z= 0

Area= 0.500 (from the Z table)

**C.** I'm not sure how to do part C of this problem. Is this just a tricky question and I    should find Pr(10>Y<11)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We assume, perhaps unreasonably, that the lengths are normally distributed.

C) Let $A$ be the event the thing is less than $11$, and let $B$ be the event the thing is between $10$ and $12$.

We want the **conditional probability** $\Pr(A|B)$.

By the usual formula for conditional probability, we have
$$\Pr(A|B)=\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}.$$

Finding $\Pr(B)$ was Problem B) (which was not done correctly).

To find $\Pr(A\cap B)$, we want the probability of being between $10$ and $11$. This is a problem of a nature similar to B).

**Remark:** For probability $10\lt Y\lt 12$, one way is to find $\Pr(Y\lt 12)$ (this is $0.5$) and **subtract** the probability that $Y\le 10$. You know how to find $\Pr(Y\le 10)$, since you did something similar correctly in A).

At an intuitive level, even without the conditional probability formula, it is probably clear that the conditional probability that $Y\lt 11$ given that $Y$ is between $10$ and $12$ is
$$\frac{\Pr(10\lt Y\lt 11)}{\Pr(10\lt Y\lt 12}.$$

Comment: Great. So, for part C: Pr(10<Y<11)/ Pr(10<Y<12) --> .1193/.2486 which means that .4799 chance for insect being less thank 11cm long. Thanks, I'm glad I've asked, using conditional probability for part C makes a perfect sense.